# Turn off monitor light using java

Tags: java

Is there any way to turn off the monitor screen light using java code like a screen saver does.Pressing a button will turn off the screen light and for pressing any key or mouse move the light comes back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a function that is already implemented by your operating system. It is tied in so deeply within operation system and hardware dependent functions turning it’s difficult to do it in pure Java, anyway you can easily do it on C++

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
  int seconds = 10;
  clock_t delay = seconds *CLOCKS_PER_SEC, start = clock();

  while(clock() - start < delay)
    SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 2);

  SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: We are here for that! I'm glad I helped you

Comment: BTW I made a .exe using c++ and executed it using Java Runtime class. :)

Answer (score 5):

> ***Is there any way to turn off the monitor screen light using java code like a screen saver does.***

Not in a platform independent way using the standard API. You'll have to rely on some system specific commands.

On a Linux box, you could for instance do

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("xset dpms force off");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a highly system specific thing.  Definitely operating system specific, and possibly hardware specific too.

Java is not the best choice for this kind of thing.  It is probably possible, but there are better ways ... like running native OS utilities or writing a little C application to call a native code library.

Comment: Ok Thanks.I better try it on C++

Comment: @MamunSardar You could try using JNI or JNA to add c++ code to java